# Simple XML Load File not working

Tags: php, simplexml, yql

how come this isn't working:

```
$url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fmeta%22%20and%20url%3D%22http://www.cnn.com%22&format=xml&diagnostics=false";

$xml = (simplexml_load_file($url))
```

I get multiple errors telling me the HTTP request failed. Ultimately I want to get the results from this file into an array eg

Description = CNN.com delivers the latest breaking news etc.

Keywords = CNN, CNN news, CNN.com, CNN TV etc.

But this initial stage isn't working. Any help please?

**EDIT**
Additional information:

Errors:

```
warning: simplexml_load_file(http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20xpath%3D%22//meta%22%20and%20url%3D%22http://www.cnn.com%22&format=xml&diagnostics=false) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
# warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20xpath%3D%22//meta%22%20and%20url%3D%22http://www.cnn.com%22&format=xml&diagnostics=false"
```

- From my phpinfo():
  allow_url_fopen  On  On
- PHP version 5.2.11
- Think it's valid (http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20xpath%3D%22//meta%22%20and%20url%3D%22http://www.cnn.com%22&format=xml&diagnostics=false)

Comment: i tested this on my local xampp-installation and i can't reproduce your error messages. my script: http://pastie.org/2895218. could you please try to open the requested page in your browser, save it as test.xml, upload it to your server and try a `simplexml_load_file("test.xml");`? do you get the same errors when you try this?

Comment: I tried your script (no luck) but then with a local file as you suggest and it DID work! So what does this mean? Thanks for your great help thus far...

Comment: hmmm... there must be something wrong with your server- oder php-settings - but i've no idea what... give me some more time: i'll be back

Comment: What version of libxml are you using? (`phpinfo()` will tell you)

Comment: Add `error_reporting(-1);` at the beginning of your script and also check your `phpinfo()` and make sure that "http" appears in the "Registered PHP Streams" section.

Comment: The error reporting line doesn't seem to change anything; and http does indeed appear there.

Comment: Does a `file_get_contents` and `simplexml_load_string` combination help?

Comment: You will need to explain this a bit more, I'm afraid... (perhaps give some code I can try.) Thanks.

Comment: `$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));`

Comment: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! on that too, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**(Note: Potentially useless answer once a real answer has been found…)**

---

While you're figuring out the XML problem (keep working on it!) know that you can also get the YQL response back as JSON.  Here's a quickie example:

```
$url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+%2A+"
     . "from+html+where+xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fmeta%5B%40name%3D%27"
     . "Keywords%27+or+%40name%3D%27Description%27%5D%22+and+"
     . "url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com%22&format=json&diagnostics=false";

// Grab YQL response and parse JSON
$json   = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($json, TRUE);

// Loop over meta results looking for what we want
$items = $result['query']['results']['meta'];
$metas = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $metas[$item['name']] = $item['content'];
}
print_r($metas);
```

Giving an array like (text truncated for the screen):

```
Array
(
    [Description] => CNN.com delivers the latest breaking news and …
    [Keywords] => CNN, CNN news, CNN.com, CNN TV, news, news online …
)
```

Note that the YQL query ([try it in the console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fmeta[%40name%3D%27Keywords%27%20or%20%40name%3D%27Description%27]%22%20and%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com%22)) is slightly different to yours, to make the PHP simpler.

Comment: Hi, this is great, but I want all the meta data, not just the description and keywords. The script needs to be applicable to every site, so it can parse every meta tag the site throws at it, not just those on a specified list. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, change the YQL query to be less restrictive (like your original). Note that not all meta tags will contain `name` and `content` attributes.

Comment: I actually just tried your code and unfortunately I get similar errors: `file_get_contents(http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+%2A+from+html+where+xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fmeta...) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!` and `warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` What could be wrong????

Comment: This is a long-shot but do you have a firewall between wherever you're running the script from and the outside world? Try using cURL to see if it also gets blocked. Can you telnet to query.yahooapis.com?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how to form a cURL request (is there some simple code I could try?) and I don't have a telnet client. Seems a shame that in my development environment (locahost) things don't work that will probably work in my production environment (ie the web).

Comment: For a basic example of using cURL: http://php.net/curl.examples-basic . You also didn't answer my hunch about a firewall being in the way: do you have one set up between you and the outside world?

Comment: This was correct, the code worked when I changed internet connections, must've been a firewall....

Comment: Good to hear you found the issue. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the XML is GETable. As for valid, it lacks `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, yet I think it's not required.

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="5" yahoo:created="2010-03-09T05:09:03Z" yahoo:lang="en-US" yahoo:updated="2010-03-09T05:09:03Z" yahoo:uri="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?q=select+*+from+html+where+xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fmeta%22+and+url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com%22"><results><meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 26 Sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/><meta content="1800;url=?refresh=1" http-equiv="refresh"/><meta content="CNN.com delivers the latest breaking news and information on the latest top stories, weather, business, entertainment, politics, and more. For in-depth coverage, CNN.com provides special reports, video, audio, photo galleries, and interactive guides." name="Description"/><meta content="CNN, CNN news, CNN.com, CNN TV, news, news online, breaking news, U.S. news, world news, weather, business, CNN Money, sports, politics, law, technology, entertainment, education, travel, health, special reports, autos, developing story, news video, CNN Intl" name="Keywords"/><meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type"/></results></query><!-- total: 250 -->
```

Tested it on my local server (PHP 5.3), no errors reported. I've used your source code and it works. Here's a print_r():

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [results] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [meta] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [content] => HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 26 Sep 2004), see www.w3.org
                                    [name] => generator
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [content] => 1800;url=?refresh=1
                                    [http-equiv] => refresh
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [content] => CNN.com delivers the latest breaking news and information on the latest top stories, weather, business, entertainment, politics, and more. For in-depth coverage, CNN.com provides special reports, video, audio, photo galleries, and interactive guides.
                                    [name] => Description
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [content] => CNN, CNN news, CNN.com, CNN TV, news, news online, breaking news, U.S. news, world news, weather, business, CNN Money, sports, politics, law, technology, entertainment, education, travel, health, special reports, autos, developing story, news video, CNN Intl
                                    [name] => Keywords
                                )

                        )

                    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [content] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
                                    [http-equiv] => content-type
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'd suggest you to encode the URL, but that's already done. You could try performing the query with cURL.