# parse special character xml file using simplexml

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml, special-characters

Apologies if there is an obvious answer (and I know there are about 1000 of these similar questions) - but I have spent two days trying to attack this without success. I cannot seem to crack why I get a null response...

Short background: the following works just fine

```
$xurl= new SimpleXMLElement('https://gptxsw.appspot.com/view/submissionList?formId=GP_v7&numEntries=1', NULL,    TRUE);
$keyname = $xurl->idList->id[0];
echo $keyname;
```

this provides a response: a unique key like uuid:d0721391-6953-4d0b-b981-26e38f05d2e5

however I try a similar request (which ultimately would be based on first request) and get a failure.  I've simplified code as follows...

```
$xdurl= new SimpleXMLElement('https://gptxsw.appspot.com/view/downloadSubmission?formId=GP_v7[@version=null%20and%20@uiVersion=null]/GP_v7[@key=uuid:d0721391-6953-4d0b-b981-26e38f05d2e5]', NULL, TRUE);
$keyname2 = $xdurl->data->GP_v7->SDD_ID_N[0];
echo $keyname2;
```

this provides null.  And if I try something like 
    echo $xdurl->asXML(); 
I get an error response from the site (not from PHP).

Do I need to eject from SimpleXMLElement for the second request?  I've read about using XPath and about defining the namespace, but I'm not sure that either would be required: the second file does have two namespaces but one of them isn't used and the other has no prefix for elements.  Plus I have tried variations of those - enough to think that my problem/error is either more global in nature (or oversight due to inexperience).

For purposes of this request I have no control over the formatting of either XML file.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `simplexml_load_file()`?

Comment: trying the equivalent load command produces same errors - it will load the first example but will fail second example (with or without white spaces in title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Matze for getting me on right track.
Issue is that URL has special characters that SimpleXMLElement cannot parse without help.

Solution: add urlencode() command like the following

```
$fixurl = urlencode('https://gptxsw.appspot.com/view/downloadSubmission?formId=GP_v7[@version=null and     @uiVersion=null]/GP_v7[@key=uuid:d0721391-6953-4d0b-b981-26e38f05d2e5]');
$xdurl= new SimpleXMLElement($fixurl, NULL, TRUE);
$keyname2 = $xdurl->data->GP_v7->SDD_ID_N[0];
echo $keyname2;
```

this provided the answer (in this case 958)

Comment: That's interesting since my originally provided solution using the unescaped URL without further manual encoding worked for me on my local machine - so I think my version of PHP/SimleXMLElement handles it differently than yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go: *SimpleXMLElement* seems to re-escape (or incorrectly handle in some way) already url-escaped characters like white spaces. Try:

```
$xdurl= new SimpleXMLElement('https://gptxsw.appspot.com/view/downloadSubmission?formId=GP_v7[@version=null and @uiVersion=null]/GP_v7[@key=uuid:d0721391-6953-4d0b-b981-26e38f05d2e5]', NULL, TRUE);
$keyname2 = $xdurl->data->GP_v7->SDD_ID_N[0];
echo $keyname2;
```

and you should be fine.

(FYI: I debugged this by manually creating a local copy of the XML request result named "foo.xml" which worked perfectly.)

Comment: I think you are on to something: I can get local version to work but the version you have still does not - I get messages similar to [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410031/simple-xml-load-file-not-working[/link].  Notice that person's request also had a URL with nonstandard characters.  I have to assume (since my first request to exact same site worked) that the problem is the [ ] @ ? or similar.